# My search bar is not synchronous with the YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, meteor

The YouTube API takes a very short amount of time for a request to its server to come back (In my case, I'm sending a search query). However, it's still too slow to make my program synchronous.

This is the Search Bar handler:

```
 Template.search_bar.events({
    'keypress #query' : function (evt,template) {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (evt.which === 13){
                var url = template.find('#query').value;
                $("#query").val('');
                //YoutubeAPI calls go here
        Template.list.search_get(url);

                Links.insert({sess:Template.list.my_playlist_id,youtube_link:Session.get("search_results").items[0].snippet.title});
                }
       }
  });
```

And this is what carries out the GET call:

```
Template.list.search_get= function(str){
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({part:'snippet',q:str});

    request.execute(function(response) {
        str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
        str = JSON.parse(str);
        Session.set("search_results",str);
    });
}
```

The top search result is displayed in a list, however the result is always displayed **one** result behind. Meaning the first search will yield `undefined` because the Session variable wouldn't have updated by that time, the second search will yield the results of the first search, and so on.

Any input on how I could go about resolving this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Session` for this one. Try moving the `Links.insert` routine to your request callback, and things should start to look better ;)

Comment: You've already done it in your question. The nature of your `search_get` is asynchronous so you cannot expect that the `Session` will be updated immediately.